# logrotate in SUSE Enterprise Server

Tags: cron, suse, logrotate

I can't manage to work this dummy config file (I placed it in etc/logrotate.d):

```
/var/log/test_log/mylogfile {
copytruncate
dateext
rotate 3
compress
missingok
size=+2
}
```

I write to the log (echo "hello world" > /var/log/test_log/mylogfile) but it's just not working.

Doing cat /etc/crontab shows:

```
# check scripts in cron.hourly, cron.daily, cron.weekly, and cron.monthly
#
-*/15 * * * *   root  test -x /usr/lib/cron/run-crons && /usr/lib/cron/run-crons >/dev/null 2>&1
```

I later redirected the output to in this way:

```
-*/15 * * * *   root  test -x /usr/lib/cron/run-crons && /usr/lib/cron/run-crons > /var/log/test_log/log_logrotate
```

But nothing happened.

Should I add another line in the etc/crontab to force the cron.dayly to happen kind of like in Ubuntu:

```
25 6    * * *   root    test -x /usr/sbin/anacron || ( cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily )
```

or the problem may be in the /usr/lib/cron/run-crons file??

I am under SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 SP2

Comment: how often you want to rotate ?

Comment: @tdi I would like to do it dayly but my example is just a dummy example. I can't run any logrotate file. Anyway the size option should trigger the logrotate, shouldn't it?

Comment: see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found an answer to my question. The issue was tricky because "**the newer Cron versions of Linux may run abit differently than in older versions**" to what I was used to.

It seems now Cron consists of the script usr/lib/cron/run-crons, which checks whether cron.dayly in /var/spool/cron/lastrun/ is older than one day (By default it checks if it is more than or exactly 1440 minutes since lastrun). Or if we want the cron.dayly to run at a fixed time we should set the `DAILY_TIME` variable in the /etc/sysconfig/cron file to a time (i.e:"12:00") and it will be run at that time dayly (within 15minutes).

Note (from the /etc/sysconfig/cron comments):Due to the fact that cron script runs only every 15 minutes, it will only run on xx:00, xx:15, xx:30, xx:45, not at the accurate time you set.

I found the answer [here](https://www.suse.com/communities/conversations/why-are-my-cron-jobs-not-running-when-expected/):

Comment: The only thing that still confuses me is the - at the beginning of the crontab task:

`-*/15 * * * *   root  test -x /usr/lib/cron/run-crons && /usr/lib/cron/run-crons >/dev/null 2>&1`

Answer (score 0):

logrotate runs either when time period is given `weekly`, `daily` and so on, or in the case of size when filesize exeeds the given size.

Just put there `size=2`, instead of `size=+2`, and it should work.

> size size
>
> Log files are rotated when they grow bigger then size bytes.  If
> size  is  followed by M, the size if assumed to be in megabytes.
> If the k is used, the size is in kilobytes. So  size  100,  size
> 100k, and size 100M are all valid.

Comment: No, my configuration file is fine. If I run `/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf` it does what it is suppossed to do so I guess the problem seems to be in the etc/crontab file, doesn't it?

Comment: just try this: `logrotate  YOUR CONFIG`

Comment: that is exactly what I did: `/usr/sbin/logrotate /etc/logrotate.conf`. And as I said before that do work, but what I want is the logrotate to be done automatically.